# Hosted Zone Id for CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have 2 hosted zone with same name (one private and another public), I am trying to use the public hosted zone id in my cloudformation template for it to register when creating the stack. Each time it fails complaining

> No Such Hosted Zone ID

When using Zone name it used to work (before 2 identical names). I am not able to pinpoint what might be causing the issue. I have full access on the AWS account and cloudformation is running with my cred. Below is the template:

```
PublicHostedZone:
Type: String
Description: Provide existing Amazon Route 53 public hosted zone
AllowedValues:
  - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Default: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 

Route53Publicrecord:
Type: 'AWS::Route53::RecordSet'
Properties:
  HostedZoneID: !Join 
    - ''
    - - !Ref PublicHostedZone
      - .
  Comment: DNS name for load balancer.
  Name: !Join 
    - ''
    - - !Ref InstanceName
      - .
      - !FindInMap 
        - RegionMap
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - DNSregion
      - .
      - !Ref PublicHostedZone
      - .
  Type: A
  AliasTarget:
    HostedZoneId: !Join 
      - ''
      - !FindInMap 
        - RegionMap
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - DNSHostedZoneId        
    DNSName: !Ref ALBName
```

Thank you!

Comment: `HostedZoneID` is just an id something like `Z23ABC4XYZL05B` , shouldn't be joined with `.`

Comment: Thank you. I changed the HostedZoneName to ID and forgot all about the '.'

Comment: Did it work or still same issue?

Comment: After i removed the 'join' and the '.' in right places and added the hostedzonename in some places it worked :)